# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string `904 522 9773`, essentially a phone number, with spaces I'm trying to get rid of. I'm calling `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")` but the `" "` character isn't getting replaced. Any reason for this?

Here's my code:

```
       override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            func findContacts() -> [CNContact] {

                let store = CNContactStore()

                let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName),
                    CNContactImageDataKey,
                    CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]

                let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)


                var contacts = [CNContact]()

                do {
                    try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (let contact, let stop) -> Void in

                        if contact.phoneNumbers.count != 0 {

                            for phoneNumber:CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers {

                                let a = phoneNumber.value as! CNPhoneNumber

                                var number: String = "\(a.stringValue)"

                                if number.characters.first == "1" {

                                    let start = number.startIndex

                                    number.removeAtIndex(start)

                                }

                                // number = +1 (904) 522-9773

                                let b = number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+1", withString: "") // (904) 522-9773
                                let c = b.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(", withString: "") // 904) 522-9773
                                let d = c.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "") // 904 522-9773
                                let e = d.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "") // 904 522 9773
                                let f = e.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") // SHOULD BE 9045229773

                                print(f) // BUT is printing 904 5229773
                            }

                        }


                    })
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } 

                return contacts


            }
```

Comment: `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` returns a new string. it doesn't mutate the current one

Comment: Yeah I know. Should've clarified. See updated.

Comment: `spacelessNum` contains no space for me

Comment: This code works fine.

Comment: No, it prints "9045229773\n". What version of Swift are you using? And are you defining your `number` string as a string literal with spaces you typed in with the keyboard? There is a "non-breaking space" character that would not match an normal space.

Comment: Ok updated is my full code. Most numbers have the same format, but some print out as `9045229773` and others `904 5229773`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let origin = "904 522\u{00a0}9773" // \u{00a0} is a no-break space
let result = String(origin.characters.filter { !" \u{00a0}".characters.contains($0) })

print(origin) // "904 522 9773"
print(result) // "9045229773"
```

This removes the usual whitespace and non-breaking space.

Edit:

```
let spaces = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()
let result = origin.utf16.filter { !spaces.characterIsMember($0) }.map { Character(UnicodeScalar($0)) })
```

This is similar (also removes tabs), but a bit longer. If you prefer the one line solution but also wants to remove a tab (or any other), you can simply add it to the string in the closure.

I just took a quick look at your code and you can remove `(`, `)`, `-` together with the spaces in one line. Just add those characters to the closure:

```
let result = String(number.characters.filter { !" \u{00a0}()-".characters.contains($0) })
```

This could be done with the `+1` as well, but requires a bit more work.

Edit:

Another approach is to filter out all the numbers out of the string. This is more useful if your string consists of lots of other characters which you want to filter out:

```
let filter = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()
let result = String(origin.utf16.filter { filter.characterIsMember($0) }.map { Character(UnicodeScalar($0)) })
```

Comment: Thank you!! Would you mind explaining why this works but `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")` doesn't?

Comment: One reason I can think of is as Duncan C said, there might be a "non-breaking space" in your string which `!" \u{00a0}".characters.contains($0)` takes care of. You could test it out by removing `\u{00a0}`.

Comment: Updated the question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to handle phone numbers, use a decent library, like libPhoneNumber. Phone numbers *are complicated*. For example, the best code that I could have possibly written myself would have been broken for Italian numbers. Your code on the other hand only has any chance to work in the USA and Canada. Many unhappy users.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is that in Swift? Would you mind providing a link?

Answer (score -3):

```
let myString = "904 522 9773"
let result = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
print(result = \(result))
```

Goodluck!

Comment: OP specify swift tag but you post objective-c code. You should edit and provide code with swift language.